# Building OpenJDK 8 on Windows 10 from sources

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to build OpenJDK 8 on Windows 10 using cygwin, but configure cannot detect the Visual Studio 2022 bin folder, even though I explicitly specified it in [bash configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48zO0.png)

The command I use to run configure: bash configure --with-tools-dir="/cygdrive/d/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/"

Comment: *I am trying to build OpenJDK 8 on Windows 10 using cygwin* [Why so?](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)

Comment: @g00se Are you pointing out the ineffectiveness of XY questions? If so, I would suggest being more direct.

Comment: @erickson Not direct yet as there might be a legitimate reason. That's why I'm asking the question. But the (real) goal has not been stated

Comment: @g00se I think I have asked my question correctly enough, my goal is to build OpenJDK 8 on Windows 10

Comment: Are you not going to use it to run apps then?

Comment: I am going to, otherwise why would I build OpenJDK?

Comment: OK, so we're getting *closer* to your actual goal, which leads me to the question: why don't you just install it?

Comment: Note that the console reports that the Visual Studio Code installation is found in some path containing `VC` (uppercase), but the tool seems to be looking in some path containing `vc` (lowercase). While Windows is case-insensitive, Cygwin isn't, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @g00se I need to modify the jvm.dll source code to debug my agent to see how the jvm gets the JVMTI Environment when I connect the agent to my application

Comment: @MCEmperor Maybe, but the thing is that Visual Studio does not create a bin folder in the vc folder, I tried creating a bin folder in VC and moving the files from VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/ there, but it did not help.